# I locked myself out of my BIOS

Tags: boot, bios

That sounds stupid, but I managed to lock myself out of my BIOS.

I have an ASUS ZenBook UX305FA with Arch Linux installed. By pressing ESC during the POST sequence I can enter the boot menu and then enter setup from there. In the security options I installed passwords for admin, user, hdd-admin and hdd-user. I did it because why not and after rebooting I was asked for them. Well, everything works as expected but now I want to revert that. Problem: I cant enter the setup anymore. Pressing ESC does not do anything.

So.... How can I enter setup and revert these changes or remove the passwords **without** removing the cmos battery?

Comment: There is always a sequence to get in; first one password, then the other (a hierarchy of access). Or are you not saying that you forgot the password? You are also mixing *enter the boot menu* and *enter the setup* in your text. Please [edit] and make sure exactly which steps fail and why.

Comment: No no, I know the passwords. It's just interessting that neither ESC nor F2 bring me into setup at any point, even after entering the passwords.

Comment: [Is Fastboot on](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/new-ux305fa-owner-boot-to-bios-in-emergency-fastboot-questions.771710/)? BTW Plenty of hits on [ASUS ZenBook UX305FA BIOS](https://www.google.nl/search?q=ASUS+ZenBook+UX305FA+BIOS)

Comment: Yes, FastBoot is enabled by default.

Comment: Removing the CMOS battery won't clear the passwords (they'd be pretty useless if it did ;) ).  Try repeatedly tapping ESC during boot from A) a cold start, and B) a soft reboot; perhaps one way or the other will provide better results.

Comment: @LuMa - disable fast boot.

Comment: I have an ASUS too, but different model. Try to disable fast boot as suggested by Ramhound. You should tap on the ESC a the time when you see the Logo

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there are some sort of jumpers on the motherboard, which when sorted or connected in some sort of method, resets BIOS information. 

Here's one link : http://www.yumapk.com/how-to-get-rid-of-the-bios-password-on-asus-zenbook-ux32a-db51.html


Here's one other link for HP computers : http://science.opposingviews.com/reset-hp-laptop-bios-password-8582.html

Comment: So which jumpers should **short** specifically?  Just so you know you can't "sort" a jumper.  You provided good references, so bring the relevant information into your question, and tailor it to the author's situation.  of your course your suggestion basically does exactly what the author didn't want to have happen, his configuration, to be reset.